# List running java processes in a linux host via ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to list the java processes running in the mentioned hosts. However am not getting the desired o/p

Have created a ansible-playbook file to read the shell commands.

````
 name: 'Check the running java processes'
 hosts: all
 tasks:
   - name: 'check running processes'
     shell: ps -ef | grep -i java```

output: PLAY [Check the running java processes] ****************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [target1]
ok: [target2]

TASK [check running processes] *************************************************
changed: [target1]
changed: [target2]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
target1                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
target2                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

However, it's not listing the processes.
````

Comment: I can't test it right now but maybe command would work better than shell. My thinking is shell will have its own stdout separate from the ansible login

Comment: @Terry: [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) module will raise an error because of the pipe in OP's command -> `The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not work. Use the shell module if you need these features.`. Moreover, it would not change anything to the current problem even with a simpler command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see the result with your actual playbook by running ansible in verbose mode.

However, the good way to do this is to [`register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the output of your task and display its content in a debug task (or use it in any other task/loop).

To know how your registered var looks like, you can read the doc about [common](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common-return-values) and [`shell`'s specific](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common-return-values) return values... or you can simply debug the full var in your playbook and have a look at it.

Here is an example just to get the full `stdout` of the command:

```
---
- name: Check the running java processes
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Check running processes
      shell: ps -ef | grep -i java
      register: ps_cmd

    - name: Show captured processes
      debug:
        var: ps_cmd.stdout
```